# How to set dynamic text in Adobe Animate

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, adobe-animate

I've just started trying adobe animate, and I want a text field to be a certain number.

```
this.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,hello);

function hello(event) {
    var year = (this.currentFrame / 5) + 927;
    testText.text = "here is the text";
}
```

(There is a "testText" in the library)
It's not doing anything, how do I fix it? I've searched the adobe forums and a few forum questions and it's not helping at all. They all do the same thing as I did or use some complicated code with stuff that doesn't work.

Comment: First and foremost, just design a **TextField** on the stage, select that **TextField** on the stage and open its properties, make it the **Dynamic** text (static texts cannot change), give it the *instance name*, say, **T**, then add a script to the same frame: **T.text = "abc";** That's about it. The thing you did with the library sounds wrong: you just cannot have a **TextField** in the library without a container, also, library and its content just cannot be accessed in runtime, it's a palette of thing to put on stage, no more than that.

Comment: Now it's saying "eeee" like something's wrong

Comment: @Bfyuvf You need to click on a button saying **embed** in your **textField** properties / settings. You need the "embed" button shown next to "style" settings in [this picture](https://helpx.adobe.com//content/dam/help/en/animate/using/web-fonts/jcr_content/main-pars/procedure/proc_par/step_1187704668/step_par/image/font_use.png.img.png)